# C language: How to pass a variable arguments list of void* to a function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am trying to pass a variable arguments list of void* elements to a function in C.

1. How do I do this?
2. How do I calculate the number of items in the list?
3. How do I loop through the var-args list and pass each void* item
   to another function that takes a void* item as its parameter?

This is what I have done, but it is not working.

```
 void AddValues(List* data, void* args, ...) {

 int len = sizeof (args) / sizeof (*args);


 for(int i=0;i<len;i++){ processItem(args[0]); }

 }

 void processItem(void* item){

 }
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic

Comment: You can't calculate the length that way.  `sizeof (args) / sizeof (*args)` = `sizeof(void*) / sizeof(void)` but void has no size.  Functions that take varargs lists need to be able to determine the size from some other source:  - another parameter (printf uses the number of % in the format string) or a special value (like all the void* pointers point to things and the last one is NULL)  So either the first parameter has to be the size or your last void* must have a special sentinel value.

Comment: @gbenroscience Your `void*` parameter has absolutely nothing to do with the `...` for var-args. You cannot deference a `void*`, and if you could it wouldn’t tell you how many things were pointed to or anything because as far as the compiler is concerned it’s just a pointer to `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How do I calculate the number of items in the list?*

You can't. It must be provided or derivable.

> *How do I loop through the var-args list and pass each void* item to another function that takes a void* item as its parameter?*

As documented in [Variadic Functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic),

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void AddValues(int count, ...) {
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, count);

   for(int i=count; i--; )
      processItem(va_arg(args, void*));

   va_end(args);
}
```

Example usage:

```
void* p1 = ...;
void* p2 = ...;
void* p3 = ...;
void* p4 = ...;

AddValues(4, p1, p2, p3, p4);
```

---

It depends on what you are doing, but you should probably be using an array instead of variadic parameters.

```
void AddValues(int count, const void** args) {
   for(int i=count; i--; )
      processItem(*(args++));
}
```

Example usage:

```
#define C_ARRAY_LENGTH(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof((a)[0]))

void* ptrs[4];
ptrs[0] = ...;
ptrs[1] = ...;
ptrs[2] = ...;
ptrs[3] = ...;

AddValues(C_ARRAY_LEN(ptrs), ptrs);
```

Or (if the pointers can't be NULL):

```
void AddValues(const void** args) {
   while (*args != NULL)
      processItem(*(args++));
}
```

Example usage:

```
void* ptrs[5];
ptrs[0] = ...;
ptrs[1] = ...;
ptrs[2] = ...;
ptrs[3] = ...;
ptrs[4] = NULL;

AddValues(ptrs);
```

Comment: so va_arg and va_end are inbuilt functions?

Comment: @gbenroscience Standard library functions. About as close to built-in as you get. There may be some changes standard revision to standard revision, but C tends to be conservative with it's changes to avoid blowing up coming up on 50 years of legacy code.

Comment: Yes, I just found it. Thanks